# Why does setTimeout not execute properly inside a loop VS inside a recursive function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, recursion, settimeout, synchronous

This code waits one second and executes all the iterations at once:

```
for(let i=0;i<4;i++){
    setTimeout(function(){console.log("Hello")},1000)
}
```

This code executes properly as expected:

```
var i = 0;
function loop(){
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Hello" + " " + Number(i+1))
    i++
    if(i<3){
        loop()
    }
},1000)

loop()
```

My question is why? Does this have to do with the synchronous single-threaded nature of JavaScript? how so? An explanation as to why this is happening is my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first code does this:

"Set four timeouts to go off in one second from now"

Your second code is:

"Set a timeout and alert the value of `i`, increment `i` and if the loop isn't over then set a new timeout"

Quite a difference! The key thing is, setting multiple timeouts isn't like a queue, they will all start from when you call them.

Comment: Can I achieve the second code's result using a loop?

Comment: you can use `setInterval` instead, and stop it after 4 iterations

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to multiply the delay by `i`

```js
var f = function(){console.log("Hello")};
for (let i=0; i<4; ++i) setTimeout(f, i * 1000);
```